# Destruct Parse.Object instance

Tags: ecmascript-6, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to know an easy way to destruct a Parse.Object instance.

Lets say I have an Parse.Object instance with following attributes:

```
const Address = new Parse.Object<Address>("Address", {
   address: "St. Nowhere",
   zipCode: 33111,
   timezoneOffset: -2,
   dayLightSavingTime: true
})
```

I want to destruct `Address` to get is't properties values easily. Like:

```
const {
   address,
   zipCode,
   ...OtherAttributes
} = Address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found that it is easy as:

```
const {
  address,
  zipCode,
  ...OtherAttributes
} = Address.toJSON()
```

Be advised that if you are using Typescript and `Address` is possible `undefined` you will get the error:

```
TS2339: Property 'address' does not exist on type '(ToJSON  & JSONBaseAttributes) | undefined'.
```

One solution would be:

```
const {
  address,
  zipCode,
  ...OtherAttributes
} = Address.toJSON() ?? {}
```

Caution with `Date` attributes. They are transformed to `{ __type: 'Date'; iso: string; }` where `iso` is the date in ISO 8601 format.